# Is it possible to see DataFrame in wxpython GUI?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I have created a `dataFrame` with `Pandas`  which has 3 columns with more than 100 records. Now I am trying to show this `dataFrame` to the user through PythonGUI tool, wxPython, but I am not sure if it is possible to show `dataFrame` with wxPython.

I tried to show it in a form of `MessageDialog` but got an error message. It seems like I need to create a grid with wxPython and get values for each cell to show the table, but is there any simpler way to show my table to the end-users?

Here's an example of my `dataFrame` df6

```
                 email firstname   lastname
1        ah@example.com   Andrew   H
2        ah@example.com   Andrew   H
3      andy@example.com   Andrew   M
4        am@exmaple.com   Andrew   M
```

And here's the code I tried to make a `MesssageDialog` in wxPython.

```
            def OnBtnClick(self, event):
                dialog = wx.MessageDialog(self, df6, 'Result', wx.OK)
                dialog.ShowModal()
                dialog.Destroy()
```

When I run the above code, I still get the mainframe to call a dialogue box but if I click the button, I get the following error message.

```
dialog = wx.MessageDialog(self, df6, 'Result', wx.OK)
TypeError: MessageDialog(): argument 2 has unexpected type 'DataFrame'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn the frame into a string or the values within into strings.
Your best bets are to use the dataframe options to turn the values into a `list` or a `dict` or the dataframe itself into a string.
e.g.

```
df.values.tolist()
df.to_dict()
```

then manipulate the data into a string

or

```
df.to_string().strip()
```

i.e.

```
dlg=wx.MessageDialog(None,df.to_string().strip(),'Result', wx.OK)
```

but this is a dirty and ugly method as it includes the indices

p.s. There may well be better methods available from people who are familiar with `pandas`, I am not.

Comment: Thank you!!! It works well and this is exactly what I wanted. Not I should work on arranging data:D